# How to use the PHP within Terminal that comes with installed Vagrant Box instead of system PHP

Tags: php, vagrant, terminal

I've provisioned a ScotchBox Vagrant Box, which is basically a LAMP stack. But I need to be able to use the PHP that comes with ScotchBox from Terminal instead of the system `php`

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Use the full path that goes to the scotchbox php.

Like so:

```
/path/to/scotchbox/php 'php commands'
```

Instead of:

```
php 'php commands'
```

Is this what you're asking? [note: I have no idea what scotchbox is, alternate php versions are standard things, so I assume there's nothing special about this type.]